# How to initialize a JavaScript array with constant values?

Tags: javascript, arrays

How do you initialize a JavaScript array with constant values?
For example, in C code I can write

```
int array[] = {1, 2, 3};
```

What is the equivalent in JavaScript?

Answer (score 12):

1: Regular:

```
 var myCars=new Array(); 
 myCars[0]="Saab";       
 myCars[1]="Volvo";
 myCars[2]="BMW";
```

2: Condensed:

```
 var myCars=new Array("Saab","Volvo","BMW");
```

3: Literal:

```
 var myCars=["Saab","Volvo","BMW"];
```

Refer this link: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_array.asp

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming your objective is to get an **immutable** array.

Note:  in the javascript arrays are also object.

we can achieve this by using **Object.freeze** or **Object.seal**

```js
'use strict'

const simpleObject =  {
  ADD_TODO : "ADD_TODO",
  DELETE_TODO :  "DELETE_TODO"
}

const immutableObject =  Object.freeze(simpleObject);

// now you can`t do update, delete or add in "immutableObject"
```

[Kindly read the MDN documentation for more detail](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze)

Comment: I too think Zoran's question means how to make the values inside the array immutable and your suggestion seems to be the answer as Javascript appears to have no way to use the const keyword for the values in an array or the members within an object.

Answer (score 1):

In the following way:

```
var array = [1, 2, 3];
```

Read more about arrays in *MDN*:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Answer (score 1):

Array object in javascript :

```
var mycars = new Array();
mycars[0] = "1";
mycars[1] = "2";
mycars[2] = "3";
```

or

```
var myCars=["one","two","three"];
```

Comment: In general it is preferable to use the literal notation of the other answers, when all initial values are given.

Comment: he is new.so just for his knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
var array = [1,2,3];
```